# Intersection of angular ray with circle

Tags: trigonometry

I have a geometric/trigonometric problem.  I will include a diagram but I know images are not ideal so I will do my best to describe the figure as well.  Sorry for the Paint diagram.  The angle corner in interior of the circle is intended to be the origin of the circle.  The value $d$ is the known distance from the left-end point to the edge of the circle, or the distance from the left-end point to the center of the circle (we know the radius so either one is an acceptable input).  The value $r$ is the (known) radius of the circle,  $\theta$ is known, and we wish to find the measure of the angle marked with a question mark.

[image: Figure]

We are given a circle of known radius and a point outside that circle at a known distance from the center.  Draw a line through the point and the center of the circle.  From the point, draw a ray towards the circle at an incline of $\theta$ from the point-circle line, where $\theta$ is small enough that the ray intersects the circle.  We now can form a right triangle inside the circle, where the base is a portion of the point-circle line and the hypotenuse is the segment from the circle's origin to the intersection of the ray with the circle.  Call $\theta_2$ the angle made between the base and hypotenuse of this new triangle.

My question is if we have an expression for $\theta_2$ in terms of $\theta$ and the given distance from the point to the circle, and the radius of the circle.

I thought I had an answer to this but it came down to me incorrectly identifying two triangles edges in the picture.  I would like to perform this calculation purely in terms of angle and distance, without reference to coordinates if possible.  If the best solution involves converting to coordinates then I accept :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...if $\phi$ is the ? angle, the sine rule gives $$\frac{\sin\theta}{r}=\frac{\sin(\theta+\phi)}{d+r}$$

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful.  To be sure I've understood, that $\theta + \phi$ is supposed to be the top angle of the triangle in my figure?  I think that angle ought to be $\pi - (\theta + \phi)$, yes?

Comment: Yes, but $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$